# How to move index of one row of Android Listview to the top

Tags: android, listview, position, android-arrayadapter

In my Listview I want the row whose app_id matches another variable named def in the android app to be the first index. In other words, instead of just filling the listview as it is already sorted, I want to basically take one of the rows and move it to the top. Is there a simple way to do this within the below ApplicationAdapter?

```
    public class ApplicationAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Application>{
    private List<Application> items;

    public ApplicationAdapter(Context context, List<Application> items) {
        super(context, R.layout.app_custom_list, items);
        this.items = items;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return items.size();
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View v = convertView;

        if(v == null) {
            LayoutInflater li = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
            v = li.inflate(R.layout.app_custom_list, null);            
        }

        Application app = items.get(position);

        if(app != null) {
            ImageView icon = (ImageView)v.findViewById(R.id.iconImg);
            TextView titleText = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.titleTxt);
            TextView descText = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.descTxt);            
            TextView creatorText = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.creatorTxt);
            TextView createdText = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.createdTxt);            
            TextView rankText = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.rankTxt);


            if(icon != null) {
                Resources res = getContext().getResources();
                String sIcon = "com.sj.jsondemo:drawable/" + app.getIcon();
                icon.setImageDrawable(res.getDrawable(res.getIdentifier(sIcon, null, null)));
            }

            if(titleText != null) titleText.setText(app.getTitle());
            if(descText != null) descText.setText(app.getDesc());
            if(creatorText != null) creatorText.setText(app.getCreator());            
            if(createdText != null) createdText.setText(app.getCreated());            
            if(rankText != null) rankText.setText(app.getRank());            
        }
```

Comment: Are you looking for drag and drop an item to top?

Answer (score 1):

1. Search the list for the matching Application instance.
2. Remove it from the list
3. Add it to the front of the list with .add(0, x)
4. Call notifyDataSetChanged() on your adapter in order to refresh the list.

Comment: This looks good, but I am not sure how to implement it. Could you show me an example?

Comment: Which step are you having a problem with?  Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: To be honest, I don't know how or where to start. I am completely new to programming in android. If you could show me an example, I might be able to learn from it.

Comment: You should start by going through android tutorials and documentation.   https://developer.android.com/guide/index.html

You're going to run into many more things that you'll need to figure out, and instead of asking a question every time you want to do something basic, you'll need to be able to figure it out yourself.